# Local Data transfer from old app to new app with same bundle identifier in coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I've been working on revamp of ios application and the biggest hurdle come into the way in the form of core data local stored data of old app users in devices because of offline mode, so while updating new app i am unable to get data of those users who were using old app,

What i've done uptill now is created demo project and copied complete CoreData Model in new project  fortunately i am getting UserDefaults stored data but not coredata stored data.

Is there's something i am missing please guide me as i have been stuck in this process.

Comment: Please provide us some code and tell us what you really want

Comment: If you install a new app with the same bundle identifier as an existing app, the new app replaces the existing app, and you should have access to all existing files, including the Core Data database.

Comment: there are two options whether you can use lightweight migration or heavyweight migration plz refer to this link -> https://shakya4577.medium.com/heavyweight-core-data-migration-51570555124b

Comment: @Chandaboy This has nothing to do with model migration

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i can't share code which helps you to understand, it's a scenario in which i am unable to access old app local data in new app model, i have tried access UserDefaults data and i am successfully getting it but not CoreData.

Comment: @FaizanAli If you have the same bundle ID then iOS replaces the old app with the new one and leaves all of the app data in place. If Core Data isn’t available then your question is missing critical details and is impossible to answer. From what you’ve asked, the answer is that you don’t do anything because the data is already there. If you can’t share any code at all and can’t add more detail, you can’t get an answer either.

Comment: @TomHarrington what code you need so you can understand the problem i am just fetching the data from model as did in old app? i think there is issue in coredata configurations it is not suitable or compatible with new project..